# How is it possible that Magento create SEO Links for products ONLY WITH the category

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, seo

> The problem:

Magento creates 2 SEO Links for a product like this:

```
product/1695/60     category/category2/productname  catalog/product/view/id/1695/category/60
```

and for the same product:

```
product/1695    productname     catalog/product/view/id/1695
```

the first is a link with the category, and the second is without but only with the productname.
But what I want is that magento creates only ONE Seo Link in fact this link WITH the category, and not this link without the category.

> The question:

How is it possible that Magento create SEO Links for products ONLY WITH the category?
I search in the admin menu and the only thing what I find is the option "use categorypath for article urls". But if I choose "YES" in this option And I rebuild the indexes I got 2 SEO Link for my article.. one without the category, and one with the categorypath.
Can somebody help me?
Thanks!

Comment: [Cross-post](http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/60131/5949).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a common problem with Magento. You do have 2 options to create the result you want:

- (harder one), you truncate table core_url_rewrite and reindex
  database with "use category path to product urls" set to no. If this
  is a live site you will have to create a redirect tool to point users
  to correct pages. I recommend the extension I've created
  https://github.com/SnowdogApps/Snowdog_Error404toolsm, it is for
  redirects :-)
- use this extension https://amasty.com/magento-unique-product-url.html , easy to install and get the job done

Comment: thanks for your answer. the problem is that the harder one is exactly the oposite of that what I want. Do you have an idea to get the oposite of it?
the extension is a good beginning, because it can generate the longest path. (with category only) the problem of the extension is that the extension generate only ONE SEO url if the product is in two categories. But we need both path of each of the category, but without the short URL (only product without category)

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you need. I don't think there is an extension which will allow you to do it and even it there was one, you need to remember about canonical links in most of the URLs.

Comment: How many products do you have? I don't think you will be able to achieve all functions by default Magento URL structure, this looks like something that needs to be customized.